# Appengine Filter and Servlet on different Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, servlets, servlet-filters

I´m trying to implement a filter for my appengine app. The filter authenticates a user and saves the currentuser in a THREAD_LOCAL variable. The problem is that the thread running the filter is a different one as the thread running the servlet. Is this the normal behavior of appengine or am I doing something wrong?

This is my filter:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        Session.removeCurrentSession();
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        SessionFactory.authorize(httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization"));
        System.out.println("Filter ThreadId: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        System.out.println("Filter ThreadId: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    } 
    finally {
        Session.removeCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

and this is my appengine login endpoint:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "users.login", path = "login", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public Message loginUser(HttpServletRequest request) throws UnauthorizedException {

    System.out.println("Servlet ThreadId: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    Session session = Session.getCurrentSession();
    System.out.println("Session: "+ session.getId() + " ThreadId: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}
```

Comment: It is definitely not a behavior you have introduced by saving the authenticated user in a THREAD_LOCAL variable. But that aside, why do you have to do that ? Why not just in request scope?

Comment: I want to access the currentuser form everywhere in my code so that i can check his role and access level in any class. I know that commiting it via request scope is probably the better & saver solution but it´s also more complex and time expensive to handle it this way.

Comment: do you have any other filters inside filter chain?

Comment: I have only one other filter and that´s the ObjectifyFilter

Answer (score 0):

Some containers have 'execute threads' which just spawn new threads for requests and go back listening for new ones. But once an end point has been reached (a Servlet), pretty much all the request processing happens from within the thread that executes the Servlet.

So one way to make it work the way you would want would be to attach the User object to a thread local variable of your end point. Between the filter and the end point itself, you could transfer the User as a request scoped variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the user for current request, do this:

```
request.setAttribute("user", user);
```

and from the API methods do this for getting the user:

```
public ApiResponse apiMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    User user = (User) request.getAttribute("user");
```